# How to write patterns for Sublime Text 2?

Tags: syntax, ide, syntax-highlighting, textmate, sublimetext2

I am using Sublime Text 2 from a long time and am venturing into a new Language called Visage. I would like to add Syntax Highlighting and other support for the language. I went through the documentation but am really confused with the `pattern` that we have to write. I am looking for some helpful tutorial from where I can understand how regular expressions work in order to  read the text and provide coloration to it. I tried out the sample given but I think it would be better to have some example which explains different constructs of a programming language for which the Syntax Highlighter is written in a proper format. So that one can understand how it works. Please let me know about any blog or tutorial that could help me or show me the way to achieve proper syntax highlighting and other stuffs. Thanks